# I have random timeouts in cypress tests

Tags: cypress

I'm working with cypress now for 3 months and I try to fix this problem for 2 months now and i really don't now how to fix it.

When i run all my tests there are a lot of tests failing. And every-time its another test (random).

The application that i'm testing has an button that is disabled and when the fields are stuffed with text, the button becomes active. 
but the problem is that cypress clicks on the button when the button is still disabled. the button needs some time to get active, now I have put the following in the code:

- cy.wait('@budgetblindsPost')
- cy.wait(500)

But this is also not working. I have less errors but I still get errors.

[Here is an example of an error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKfSU.png)

[Here is also an example of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8HCm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using `cy.wait()` all over the place may eventually solve issues related to timeout, but will make your test suite unnecessarily slow. Instead, you should increase the timeout(s)

### One-off

This command will only fail after 30 seconds of not being able to find the object, or, when it finds it, 30 seconds of not being able to click it.

```js
cy.get('#model_save', {timeout: 30000}).click({timeout: 30000});
```

Please note that your value of `500` means half a second, which may not be enough.

### Global

If you find yourself overriding the timeout with the same value in a lot of places, you may wish to increase it once for all [in the config](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts).

> defaultCommandTimeout: 4000
>   Time, in milliseconds, to wait until most DOM based commands are considered timed out