# Checking states of Slide toggle not working in Cypress Tests

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to test the states of slide-toggles within my app using Cypress.

These time out and fails the test:

```
cy.get('label.mat-slide-toggle-label').eq(2).should('be.checked')
 or
cy.get('div.mat-slide-toggle-bar').eq(2).should('be.checked')
```

Where as these pass

```
cy.get('label.mat-slide-toggle-label').eq(2).should('not.checked')
 or
cy.get('div.mat-slide-toggle-bar').eq(2).should('not.checked')
```

The only difference is that the state of the toggle has changed.

Can someone help explain why the "not.checked" tests pass, but the others don't?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview) states:

> The `<mat-slide-toggle>` uses an internal `<input type="checkbox">` 
>   to provide an accessible experience. This internal checkbox 
>   receives focus and is automatically labelled by the text content of 
>   the `<mat-slide-toggle>` element.

When Angular Material adds the switch, it adds a whole little hierarchy of elements under the outer `<mat-slide-toggle>` element; divs with classes like `mat-slide-toggle-label`, `mat-slide-toggle-bar`, etc. But it also adds a real (but hidden) `<input>` element.

The 'checked' test only applies to input elements (this is probably why your `should('not.be.checked')` tests are working--because non-input elements can *never* be checked. So, to use Cypress's `should('be.checked')` test, you need to tell Cypress to get a reference to the actual `<input>` contained within the `<mat-slide-toggle>`, and not one of the other `mat-xxx` elements.

Example:

```
cy.get('mat-slide-toggle#whateverId input').should('be.checked');
  // get reference to the single <input> inside the <mat-slide-toggle>
```

or:

```
cy.get('mat-slide-toggle#whateverId .mat-slide-toggle-input').should('be.checked');
  // get reference to the element with class "mat-slide-toggle-input" inside the <mat-slide-toggle> (which is the <input> itself)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to invite you to use the [GUI snapshots panel](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test.html#Snapshots) to better understand what could be wrong, and maybe [increase the timeout(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50772085/777285).

But in fact, I'm tempted to conclude that neither `<label>` nor `<div>` can be checked. `<input type="checkbox">` can.

Is there another property you can assert on your label ?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a element for each toggle that allows me to check the state (checked or not checked).

```
input#mat-slide-toggle-29-input.mat-slide-toggle-input.cdk-visually-hidden
```

All I need to do is change the number to related to the toggle under test.  I can check that the toggle is checked, press the master switch and then check that it is unchecked.  I will also created a test where I test each toggle individually to ensure that the toggle works in a ground and singularly.